# Applying other kernel functions in pandas plot

Tags: python, pandas, kernel-density, probability-density

I would like to know what function are used for kde plot in pandas. I also want to know how to change kde's kernel function in pandas.

```
df.plot.kde();
```

I'm still studying this feature, but the default looks like a Gaussian function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the kernel in this way:

```
 kde = KernelDensity(kernel='gaussian', bandwidth=0.2).fit(X)
```

where kernel can be: 'gaussian', 'tophat', 'epanechnikov', 'exponential', 'linear' and 'cosine'.
Take a better look here: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/density.html